# Pushing NSOpenPanel to front when opened from Mac menu bar app and new PHPicker glitching when applied to menu bar app

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a Mac menu bar app that opens the NSOpenPanel so that the user can choose an image to upload. However, when I open NSOpenPanel, it shows up in the background and is not clickable at first if that makes sense. Additionally, I also tried using Apple's new PHPicker for the Mac however it totally glitches out when I open it from the Mac menu bar app. Was wondering if anyone else has faced this problem and how they went around solving it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps use `NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` when you open the panel? Your other question seems totally separate.

Comment: Please add screenshots or video with your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first problem:

I use the following on a NSSavePanel which brings the panel window to the front of the stack.

```
let panel = NSSavePanel()
… 
panel.begin { … }
panel.orderFrontRegardless()
```

From Apple's documentation:

> orderFrontRegardless()
>
> Moves the window to the front of its level, even if its application
> isn’t active, without changing either the key window or the main
> window.
>
> Discussion
>
> Normally an NSWindow object can’t be moved in front of the key window
> unless it and the key window are in the same application. You should
> rarely need to invoke this method; it’s designed to be used when
> applications are cooperating in such a way that an active application
> (with the key window) is using another application to display data.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! I know my question was a bit vague, so I made a test app to upload but then I saw your answer!